# How to crop/resize an ImageView from right to left in width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

How would I be able to crop/resize the width of the red-bar ImageView that is shown below. So I could bring it up from 0 to 100% with a method.

I've tried ImageView.scaleX(float), but this does make the width less but from the center, instead of right to left.

(You could see this as a health bar or time bar, which I will change on condition)

[image: Red bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine with the way it "resizes" with the `setScaleX(...)`, you can easily make it resize from the left side with `setPivotX(...)` method.

Just call `setPivotX(0)` for your `ImageView` and it will scale your `View` from left.